# PowerShell Set-ADUser properties with Foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach

I tired to google and search around and not sure how to get this condition work.

Content of `userid.txt`:

```
user1
user2
```

Content of `phone.txt`:

```
phone1
phone2
```

**Code:**

```
$u = Get-Content(".\Desktop\Cubicle\userid.txt")
$p = Get-Content(".\Desktop\Cubicle\phone.txt")
foreach($uf in $u){foreach($pf in $p){Set-AdUser $uf -officephone $pf}}
```

**Error:**

```
Set-ADUser : replace
At line:1 char:49
+ foreach($uf in $u){foreach($pf in $p){Set-AdUser <<<<  $uf -officephone $pf}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (user1:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Set-ADUser : replace
At line:1 char:49
+ foreach($uf in $u){foreach($pf in $p){Set-AdUser <<<<  $uf -officephone $pf}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (user2:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

If in future i need to call more than 3 text file, how do I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach. Assuming the files contain one item per line and both files have the same length of lines.

```
$u = Get-Content ".\Desktop\Cubicle\userid.txt" 
$p = Get-Content ".\Desktop\Cubicle\phone.txt"

for($i=0; $i -lt $u.count; $i++)
{
    Set-AdUser $u[$i] -officephone $p[$i]
}
```

Comment: It works great! but if i tried this:
`for($i=0; $i -lt $u.count; $i++){Set-AdUser $u[$i] -replace @{otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber = "$p[$i]"}}`
It was successfully update but the update result for user1 is "phone1 phone2[0]" for user2 is "phone1 phone2[1]"

Comment: Remove the double quotes and try again

Comment: hi @Shay-levy, removing the double quotes will give errors:<br/>
`Set-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'.
Parameter name: otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber
At line:1 char:44
+ for($i=0; $i -lt $u.count; $i++){Set-AdUser <<<<  $u[$i] -replace @{otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber = $c[$i]}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (user1:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'.
Parameter name: otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser`

Comment: the $c was actuall $p on top.
the update to that field for user1 is `phone1 phone2[0]` for user2 is `phone1 phone2[1]`. Looks like array

Comment: And if you pass it as: "$($c[$i])"

Comment: Shay, it works!!.. why it need to be coded this way?
Thank you very much

Comment: I guess it was not parsing the way it should have (or the way you wanted to). It is using a sub-expresion, e.g $() to expand double quoted expression into a string.